# Calculating internal temperature beneath skin due to localised heat application

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I am trying to understand how I can calculate the approximate temperature (T2) 3cm beneath the human skin if a constant 45 degrees Celsius heat pad (10cm x 10cm in shape) is applied to the surface for 30 minutes.

I was thinking I could assume human flesh has a thermal conductivity of 0.3 W/m.K and the heat transfer from conduction would be Q = -k x A x (T2 - T1)/L = -0.3 x 0.01 x (T2 - 45) / 0.03 = -0.1 (T2 - 45).

However, I am not sure what to do from here. I believe I would need to make another assumption using the internal human body temperature of 37 degrees Celsius perhaps.

I would love any guidance on how I could approach this.

Comment: So how will you model the blood flow removing heat?

Comment: your question is more suited for a medical site

Comment: @SolarMike good question, it isn't my domain of expertise, so I am not too sure how to go about this, but I was hoping we could perhaps simplify the equations in some way to give us an approximate answer. Otherwise, my next best idea was to actually run an experiment using similar thermal conductivities, and just measure the temperature directly.

Comment: @jsotola perhaps, however it is a pretty niche question with more of an engineering/physics underpinning, which is why I came here

Comment: look for information in the military or space program realms ... there were some US military experiments, many decades ago, to determine the highest ambient temperature that a human could survive for some period of time ... from what I remember, the temperature reached was amazingly high

Comment: I think the skin would suffer 1st degree burn after 15 minutes for to area mentioned